# Visual Studio 2022 ASP.Net WebForms: Generate Local Resource option missing

Tags: visual-studio, webforms, localization, resources

It seems that with the latest VS 2022 update (and the new HTML-designer that comes with it), the option to generate a local resource file is missing. I'm talking about this menu item under Tools:

[image]

Does anyone know a way to get it back with this new designer they added?
Kind of annoying to have to switch to VS 2019 just to localize a new page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer: switch from the new designer (Web Live Preview) back to the Legacy Web Forms designer:

[image]

Note that the new designer was activated automatically with the update in was introduced with.

Answer (score 2):

That option appears just fine on my vs2022.

This:

[image]

This suggests you are missing some designers, and a bunch of bits and parts for web form applications.

Make sure you installed all of the older workflows and options.

tools->Get tools and features.

On the right, expand this tree:

[image]

I can't remember exact which one, but for webforms development, you do want all of these checked:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that did nothing for me. I have installed exactly the same optional features as on your screenshot and the option is still missing.

Comment: darn, as I stated, it must be something I have installed. Note that you MUST have a form open in design mode, and you MUST have the designer showing, or at the very least split view. If you don't display the web form designer (or at least split mode), then the option does not show (quite sure  VS has always been this way). So, do double check you have the web form open, and in design view, not markup view.

Comment: I know that and I have tried it that way multiple times :S
I have been working with that (terrible) designer for 10 years and I agree, it should be something that I don't have installed. Although: the option was there until a few weeks ago when that new designer was patched in.

Comment: Found the answer!