# Visual Studio 2022 - ASP.net - Error Creating Control ajax Toolkit ... Page Design

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2022, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a Visual Studio 2022 ASP.net application that now displays "Error Creating Control ajax Toolkit" when viewing the Page Design:-

[image]

The application references the AjaxControlToolKit:-

[image]

And the path is pointing to the Ajax install path:-

[image]

The application builds and runs but when viewing the design page I get the "Error Creating Control" messages.

This seems to have started very recently.

Any ideas why?

tia

Comment: Try installing the aj toolkit via nuget. See if that helps.

Comment: You should be able to add your answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just to add** to my original question It appears that the "Web Live Preview" was the issue.

I set the option back to "Legacy Web Forms Designer" and it seems ok.

I found this similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74570288/visual-studio-2022-asp-net-webforms-generate-local-resource-option-missing)

[image: VS 2022 Tools Options]

[image: Web Forms Designer - Legacy Forms Designer]